# How to use threading in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am trying to make my own audio player using ios `CoreAudio` framework in `swift`. It requires at least two threads. One thread decodes the audio file and the other thread gave hardware decoded data. Actually second thread that is passing to hardware was callback from OS so I don't care that I just have to pass required data when callback function invoked.

#### AS-IS

I used `DispatchQueue` for decoding, actually it is working well. as follwed:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    while(endOfFile) {
        // do decoding
        let res = ExtAudioFileRead(input, &frameCount,&convertedData)
    }
}
```

#### Problem

When I used DispatchQueue, CPU usage exceeded `100%`. The phone getting heated though I only played one mp3 music in my player. I don't know what was wrong.

#### Questions

1. Is there a wrong way to use `DispatchQueue`?
2. Is there a way to use another except `DispatchQueue`?

Comment: Use the time profiler instrument to identify where your app is using cpu. Also, `.background` isn't a good QoS to use. I would suggest `.utility`

Comment: Create a queue and run your code to that queue... 
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.xyz.name")
operationQueue.async {//your code with completion handler}

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice. Never use loops to wait for something, your some operation should notify when it's finished and use a completion handler.This  pattern is usually referred to as [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and it is a great way to discharge your device's battery quickly.

You should use [Completion Handler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corespotlight/cssearchquery/1649312-completionhandler) to achieve this kind of stuff.

> Completion handlers are callbacks that allow a client to perform some
>   action when a framework method or function completes its task. Often
>   the client uses a completion handler to free state or update the user
>   interface. Several framework methods let you implement completion
>   handlers as blocks (instead of, say, delegation methods or
>   notification handlers).

Follow [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/) for more details.